# Switching to SdkVersion 25 makes fragments overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Everything is working fine when I am targeting SDK version 24 in `AndroidManifest`. However, when I replace it with SDK version 25, the layouts of my fragments overlap. I have no idea why this is happening nor I know where to look for this kind of bug. I first start on the P fragment, and on click of item I go to the S fragment. When I click on the letter P in the right upper corner this is how I get back to the P fragment:

```
mFragment = PeemFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, mFragment, Integer.toString(getFragmentCount()))
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
return true;
```

But, the two layouts overlap. 
[image]
I've tried setting my fragment's layout's background color to `#ffffff` and the overlap does not happen but it is a bit slower. Also, is that the best solution?

Comment: Just set a background color to your <fragment /> in XML file.

Comment: I've tried that and it works, but as I said, it is a bit slower. Also, is that the best solution?

Comment: How are you adding the fragments to the screen? xml Fragment tag or in code?

Comment: @FrankR I am adding the fragments in code, as explained above in my question.

Comment: I don't think you need to pop the back stack if you are replacing the fragment each time. Also you are using `addToBackStack(null);` which doesn't add the fragment to the back stack. Also, what Fragment are you using the support version or the default one?

Comment: @FrankR I am using the support version.

Comment: Are all your fragments being placed into the same R.id.fragment_holder view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133465/discussion-between-esteban-and-frankr).